# What is a monospace font in iOS?

Tags: ios, fonts

*Historic question 10+ yrs old.* (`UIFont.monospacedSystemFont` now common.)

---

I want a monospace font for my UILabel in my iOS application.

Unfortunately, I could not find one. Even "American Typewriter" was not actually monospaced. What is a monospace font available in XCode?

Comment: Xcode itself doesn't ship with fonts. That said, the default font for Xcode should be Menlo at least as of Snow Leopard and Lion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50792536/3939807 For any custom font and monospaced number font

Comment: http://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2013/session_223__using_fonts_with_text_kit.pdf

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Looking at an old [listing of fonts shipped with iOS](http://daringfireball.net/misc/2007/07/iphone-osx-fonts) I see <strike>several</strike> one monospace font<strike>s</strike>.

(eg. <strike>Andale Mono, Monaco,</strike> Courier New)

---

For 2018 it's only Menlo and Courier.

Comment: Not all of those fonts are included in iOS (Andale Mono and Monaco are not).  It seems that Courier New is the only fixed-width option.

Comment: Ah yes, when I posted that I didn't read the legend correctly.

Comment: the funniest thing here is that, in the first view, this answer looks like a joke with the fact that there's only one monospace font for iOS. haha

Comment: Since iOS 7 there is Menlo font

Answer (score 84):

### iOS mono-spaced fonts

```
Courier  
Courier-Bold  
Courier-BoldOblique  
Courier-Oblique  
CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT  
CourierNewPS-BoldMT  
CourierNewPS-ItalicMT  
CourierNewPSMT  
Menlo-Bold  
Menlo-BoldItalic  
Menlo-Italic  
Menlo-Regular
```

[iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com) maintain a list of all iOS fonts.

[This webpage](http://analog.co.nz/apps/typesetter/) detects your installed system fonts and returns a fairly comprehensive list.

Comment: Please note "Menlo" and "Menlo-Regular" are Not fully mono-spaced where "Menlo-Bold" is indeed mono-spaced. For the two fonts I am seeing a small variation in width when displaying a "2" instead of other digits. Observed with both Simulator XCode 12.4 and iOS 14.4

Answer (score 38):

If your intent is to display numbers and you don't care about the specific font used, you can do this:

```
UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize(
    UIFont.systemFontSize(),
    weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
```

Comment: iOS 9 or newer, sadly

Comment: I tried this for a timer counting up which uses a SKSpriteLabel, but the label still "jumps around" with said "monospaced" system font. :-(

Comment: Menlo it is, then.

Comment: In iOS 10.2, using UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize:weight:) works for me.  My "digital timer" UILabel does not "jump around".  Either Apple has fixed it since @Jonny tried it, or UILabel does not have the bug which SKSpriteLabel has.

Comment: Ah, now I see a problem, possibly why it did not work for Jonny.  It turns out that, if you are using **size class customization** in the Attributes Inspector of Interface Builder, and put Manuel's code in `viewDidLoad()`, your code will not be effective because, at runtime, the customization is apparently done *after* `viewDidLoad()` runs, thus changing it back to the regular system font.  I just posted a [demo project with workaround for this behavior](https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CountdownUILabel).

Comment: The best thing about this solution is that it is actually (currently on iOS11) using SFUI rather than one of the other mono fonts in the system. Will look far more uniform when mixed with other text than using Menlo or Courier!

Comment: What about iOS version less than 9.0? Using regular system font ?

Comment: this font IS NOT equal widths.  bizarre.

Answer (score 15):

Adobe just released a nice monospaced font [Source Code Pro](http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2012/09/source-code-pro.html) in both TTF and OTF formats.
It's licensed with the [Open Font License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIL_Open_Font_License) so it is available for free use within applications, including commercial applications. 
You will need to add the font file as a resource in Xcode, by setting the UIAppFonts key in the info.plist to point to the SourceCodeProRegular.ttf file.

Now in your code you can set, for example:

```
    self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Source Code Pro" size:14];
```

Answer (score 10):

[Expanding upon @reggie-pinkham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22620172/922323), I built this [JS Bin for folks to use as a live test page](http://jsbin.com/bisebi/4); to save future reader's some time, here's a few screen shots using iOS Simulator on Mavericks:

#### iPad Air, iOS `8.1`

[image: ipad-air-ios-8.1]

#### iPhone 6 plus, iOS `8.1`

[image: iphone-6-plus-ios-8.1]

Answer (score 9):

As of iOS 13, **San Francisco (SF) Mono** is available. Couldn't find a way to set this in interface builder, but by code it's:

```swift
let font = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .regular)
```

Comment: Here is how to add the fonts to Xcode: Add fonts to xcode https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app?language=objc

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a monospace font for numbers, then try "Helvetica Neue".

Comment: ?? that is the most famous *NOT* monospaced font.

Comment: Agreed. But, the **numbers** are monospaced.

Comment: I second the "dangerous advice". -1

Comment: This is just what I needed! The other mono fonts all have ugly zeroes.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was struggling to find a mono system font and it didn't occur to me that some non-mono fonts could have mono spaced digits. This is what i need. After looking at this more, there's Verdana and others.

Answer (score 4):

**SwiftUI**

You can use Font's instance method `monospacedDigit`

```
Text("0123456789")
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .font(Font.custom("San Francisco", size: 20).monospacedDigit())
```

Answer (score 3):

A list of built-in fonts available on iOS: http://iosfonts.com. Courier and Menlo seem to be the only monospace fonts in there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access system fonts in monospaced with the following `Font` factory method:

```
static func system(Font.TextStyle, design: Font.Design) -> Font
```

Example:

```
let monospacedBody = Font.system(.body, .monospaced)
```

Other usage:

```
let serifTitle = Font.system(.title, .serif)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there is a good Monospace font available from Apple, that can be downloaded here: [Apple SFUI](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/)
Here is how to add the fonts to Xcode: [Add fonts to xcode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app?language=objc)