# iOS Prevent timer UILabel 'shaking' when numbers change

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, adaptive-layout

I have a `UILabel` which shows the output of a timer in the format `MM:ss:SS` (minutes, seconds, centiseconds), however it "shakes" from left to right as the width of the centiseconds changes - "11" is narrower than "33" for example.

Is there any way I can mitigate this? I've tried centring it, giving it a fixed width but they haven't seemed to help.

Comment: give a fixed width constraint to a label with highest wide possibility . For ex 33:33:33 should completely be contained in it. Give label some background color. It will solve your problem to some extent

Comment: Using textkit you can specify that all numbers should be equal width.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since iOS 9.0, the system font uses proportional digits. If you want monospaced digits, there's a variant font which you can obtain using `+[UIFont monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize:weight:]`. This only works for the system font.

If you want to work with another font, you try to ask for a monospaced variant, but there may not be one. Given a `UIFont`, you can request its `fontDescriptor`, then ask that for a similar font descriptor that's monospaced (not just for digits) using `-[UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:]` and `UIFontDescriptorTraitMonoSpace`. You can then create a new font by passing the new font descriptor to `+[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:size:]`.

However, I doubt there's a monospace variant of Impact. It's not suitable for your purpose.

Comment: And does this work for custom fonts too? In this case I'm using `Impact`

Comment: That was exactly what I meant with my comment, just couldn't find it fast enough ;)

Comment: @ChrisByatt this will not work for fonts which do not have a mono spaced digit set.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. @KenThomases answer works. Here's the Swift version:

```
// replace whatever font your using with this font instead to stop the shaking
UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 19, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
```

ie:

```
yourLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 19, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
```

FYI there are other `UIFont.Weight` weights:

`.black`, `.bold`, `.heavy`, `.light`, `.medium`, `.regular`, `.semibold`, `.thin`, `.ultraLight`

[According to this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22620172/4833705) the fonts below are system generated fonts that are also **monospaced** so they won't shake either:

*Courier*

*Courier-Bold*

*Courier-BoldOblique*

*Courier-Oblique*

*CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT*

*CourierNewPS-BoldMT*

*CourierNewPS-ItalicMT*

*CourierNewPSMT*

*Menlo-Bold*

*Menlo-BoldItalic*

*Menlo-Italic*

*Menlo-Regular*

ie:

```
// no shaking
yourLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Menlo-Regular", size: 19)
```

If your using just numeric digits then *HelveticaNeue* is also **monospaced** and it doesn't shake but it's questionable. Read the [comments below this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41176708/4833705) before using this font.

ie:

```
// no shaking but apparently you can only use numbers not letters
yourLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 19)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width, or non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each occupy the same amount of horizontal space. Examples of monospaced fonts include Courier, Courier New, Lucida Console, Monaco, and Consolas

Comment: only Courier, Courier New are included in Xcode project. But yeah those fonts have equal width per any character. nice.