# Equal and Unchanging Spacing between Characters in a label

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel

I'm trying to make a label that has equally spaced characters where the spacing doesnt change between characters (Even if the characters do). Its like a Dark Room's (Game App) map. [image]

I'v tried using a normal multi line label but if like a "." is replaced with a "P" then the character at the end of the line shifts down a line. So I'm trying to get equal unchanging spacing.

Comment: Make sure you are using monospace font

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33800583/1226963 may be helpful.

Comment: And set `textLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByCharWrapping` too

Comment: Thanks, using Courier (Monospaced font) worked