# Font Width is Different

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

apple    0.31414   (Label1) 
banana 0.41253   (Label2) 
kiwi     0.2312    (Label3)

On iOS, however, the width of a single letter is not uniform, as in this case(Editor, not this screen). It is different when it is in uppercase or lowercase, and when it is 0 or 1. I want to do the beginning of the text and the beginning of the number at the same position.

I tested it with several built-in fonts on iOS, but I could not match the position of letters and numbers.

Comment: What you are looking for is a monospace font https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962994/what-is-a-monospace-font-in-ios It's not related in iOS, it's related to the font.

Comment: This is the default behaviour of a proportional font. Either use a monospaced font or use 2 labels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it.. Thankyou! Larme and zisoft