# Xamarin iOS / android project use a font that has equal width for each character

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts

I am creating a app that will run on Android and iOS.  I need to use a font that has the same width for all of it's characters.  I will use this font in several label controls.  After searching the internet it looks like I need to import a font?
Is this true?  Or is there another way to do this?
If I do need to import a font any recommendations on the font and where to get it?

Thanks.

Comment: this is called a "monospace" font.  You should be able to find an existing font(s) on each platform that does this, or you can find a custom one online and use it if you have a license.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962994/what-is-a-monospace-font-in-ios